# Vue Computed Not Updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a computed function that I'd like to utilize but I keep getting "Computed property was assigned to but it has no setter". I am simply trying to remove all the forward slashes and the 'SYG' at the end of this: 99/KRFS/010572//SYG when it's pasted into a v-model input to achieve this: 99KRFS010572.

Here is my setup function

```
<input v-model="policyMapName" />
policy-map <span>{{ policyMapName }}</span>

setup() {
    const circuitID = ref('99/KRFS/010572//SYG');

    const policyMapName = computed(() => {
        const cID = circuitID.value;

        return cID.replace(/[/]/g, '').slice(0, -3);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a setter to your [computed](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#computed) property with a getter :

```
<input v-model="policyMapName" />
policy-map <span>{{ policyMapName }}</span>

setup() {
    const circuitID = ref('99/KRFS/010572//SYG');

    const policyMapName = computed({
      get: () => {
        const cID = circuitID.value;

        return cID.replace(/[/]/g, '').slice(0, -3);
     },
    set:(newval)=>{
        circuitID.value =newval
    }   
 });
}
```